# In jsf 1.2, defining a locale from bean causes IllegalStateException in getOutputStream

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets

I'm trying to understand how this happens and how to solve it.
I have a jsf request bean with a jsp page that looks like this: (Summarized)

```
<f:view locale="#{drcBean.userLocale}">
</f:view>
```

the backing bean code:

```
public Locale getUserLocale() {
    return new Locale("en");
}
```

And finally, when the session is started this method is called (Which sends a file to the client)

```
private void sendFile()
{
        byte[] config = ...;
        String clientFileName = "iphone.mobileconfig";

        // Prepare.
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        // File file = new File(getFilePath(), getFileName());

        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open file.
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(config);
            input = new BufferedInputStream(bais);

            // Init servlet response.
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/x-apple-aspen-config");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + clientFileName
                    + "\"");
            response.setContentLength((int) config.length);

            // if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            // logger.trace("Writing XML Script:" + new String(scriptDataByteArray));
            // }


            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Finalize task.
            output.flush();
        } catch
```

I get an `IllegalStateException` exception calling `response.getOutputStream()`
The thing I don't get is that this doesn't happen if `locale="#{drcBean.userLocale}"` is not defined. (Meaning, I omit the `locale` tag of the view and the problem disappears)

- One more evidence is that the file I do receive eventually is the JSP page mentioned which in my opinion means that a new page was sent somehow and aborted the file sending. But what does this have to do with `locale`?
- Also, if I use `<f:view locale="en">` instead of using the backing bean for the value it works fine.

Comment: What is the message with the IllegalStateException?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.ViewResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ViewResponseWrapper.java:115)

Comment: Sounds like JSF impl bug (I have however never seen this). Which impl and version are you using? Try upgrading. Mojarra 1.2 is currently at 1.2_15 which is pretty mature.

Comment: MyFace 1.2.7.
I think that the problem stems from the fact that using a EL expression in locale causes it to write something to the response and then you can't send a file anymore..

Comment: Normally, if there has been something sent to the response before you call getOutputStream(), then you get an IllegalArgumentException, but with a message 'getOutputStream has already been called for this response', but you're not getting any message at all?

Comment: I just found out in another log the exception which I missed before:java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
I'm trying to see how I can move the file sending up the jsf lifecycle to avoid having the JSP page load before the file sending is started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution to this problem is to send the file before the JSP page is loaded.
To do that I registered a phaselistener and sent the file before the JSP page.

```
public class DrcPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent pe) { 
              ..... send file here ....
        }
```

The problem was, as I suspected, that the JSP page had already started sending date to the response and when I tried to send a file from the bean it was too late.
The fix above will force the file send at a phase where the page has not started to load and therefore nothing was written to the response.

Comment: This smells a lot. How exactly are you requesting the file? By submitting a form and thus calling it inside bean's action method, right? This hack namely suggests that you're doing this inside a getter method which you attached to a JSP, which is in turn the wrong approach.

Comment: @BalusC Actually, the bean is of request scope and each request "state" is determined by the URL parameters.
The file transfer is determined by the value of URL parameters only so there is no need for any JSP page to load.
Even the submit button creates a new request with new URL parameters.
Makes more sense?

Comment: Thus, by submitting a form? OK, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to download a file to the user, why are you bothered about the locale?

Anyway, I don't know why you're getting the IllegalArgumentException. This normally happens when you try to use an OutputStream which has already been written to.

If I use the following jsp:

```
<%@ page import="uk.co.farwell.MyBean" %>

<f:view locale="en">
<%
MyBean bean = (DossierBean) pageContext.findAttribute ("bean");

bean.sendFile(response);
%>
</f:view>
```

with the following code in the bean:

```
public void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    byte[] config = "foobar".getBytes();
    String clientFileName = "iphone.mobileconfig";

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(config);
    input = new BufferedInputStream(bais);

    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/x-apple-aspen-config");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + clientFileName + "\"");
    response.setContentLength((int) config.length);

    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 1024);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.flush();
}
```

and I get an IllegalArgumentException. If this is the error you're getting, then try using a Servlet directly.

```
public final class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        byte[] config = "foobar".getBytes();

        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

        resp.setContentType("application/rtf");
        resp.setContentLength(config.length());
        resp.getOutputStream().write(config.getBytes());
        resp.getOutputStream().flush();
        resp.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

or similar. This is more reliable than using a jsp for downloading files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but I think I have found the real answer that solves this. Detailed Below

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) in the end of the action method to prevent that JSF navigates to a page (which defaults to the page from where the form is been submitted).

```
public void download() {
    sendFile();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the page has already started sending data to the response before the sendFile() was called so its too late to call `responseComplete()`

Comment: Why does this happen then? This is only explainable when you called it using some getter method hack instead of a commandbutton/link action. It's almost certainly a bug in MyFaces.